# How to solve AggregateException error showing up by using opc ua compiler?

Tags: xml, nullreferenceexception, opc-ua, invalidoperationexception

while using the Opc.Ua.ModelCompiler.exe I´ll get the following issue.

[AggregateException] Error parsing file .\Demo\example_project.xml (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) (There is an error in XML document (2, 2).)

> > > [NullReferenceException] Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> > > [InvalidOperationException] There is an error in XML document (2, 2).

Does someone know how to solve it?

Best regards